# How to sequentially and conditionally chain instantiation of different classes

Tags: python

Basically, I have a list of classes which take in the same input parameters (either `ClassX(a, **kwargs)` or `ClassX(**kwargs)` or `ClassX(b, **kwargs)`. I want to create a list of instantiated classes. Right now I sequentially go through each for creation.

Is there a way to use list comprehension effectively to make this cleaner? For example perhaps making a list of class objects and annotating those that require formal arguments (`a` and `b`) in addition to `**kwargs`? I.e. looping over something like:

`[ClassA: (None, None), ClassB: (fnA, None), ClassC: (None, fnB)]` to achieve the creation of:

`listOfClasses.append(ClassA(**kwargs))`

`listOfClasses.append(ClassB(**kwargs, a=fnA))`

`listOfClasses.append(ClassC(**kwargs, b=fnB))`

The reason I ask is because in my case I have 20-30 different classes that need to be created and appended  to the list sequentially.

To illustrate better, the exact code I am using now is the following:

```
def method(self, **kwargs):
    chain = []
    chain.append(ClassA(**kwargs))
    chain.append(ClassB(**kwargs))
    chain.append(ClassC(a=static_method_x, **kwargs))
    chain.append(ClassD(b=static_method_y, **kwargs))
    chain.append(ClassE(**kwargs))
    chain.append(ClassF(a=static_method_z, **kwargs))
    ...
```

So every instantiation follows one of three types, but `**kwargs` is always the same. The values of `a` or `b` when they are classes which require them, however, differ, and correspond to other static methods in my class. I am wondering if there is a way to make this cleaner through list comprehension with a predefined list of sequential classes and respective arguments.

Comment: Pls put some code what you are doing.

Comment: Interesting concept, but your question is a little too abstract. It would help us to understand what you want to do if you made a [mcve] that shows what you're currently doing.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of visibility, I added an example showing what I am currently doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a list tuples each containing the class to instantiate along with the extra arguments, you could use a list comprehension to instantiate each one with the merge of `kwargs` and the extra args for that.

```
def method(self, **kwargs):
    to_instantiate = [
        # (Class, extra_args)
        (ClassA, {}),
        (ClassB, {}),
        (ClassC, {'a': static_method_x})
        (ClassD, {'b': static_method_y})
        (ClassE, {})
        (ClassF, {'a': static_method_z})
    ]
    chain = [C(**{**kwargs, **extra_args}) for C, extra_args in to_instantiate]
```

The `**{**kwargs, **extra_args}` part means create a new dictionary with all the entries in `kwargs` and `extra_args`, then destructure it into arguments, like you were doing with `**kwargs` before. Note that this syntax was introduced in python 3.5. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression) if you want to understand it better and also have solutions for older python versions.

Honestly though I think this code is uglier and harder to understand than what you have. The code you wrote might be a little more verbose, but I think it is much easier to read.